# Magento stuck on billing information checkout

Tags: php, magento, checkout

I'm developing a Magento store using the version 1.9.1.0 and I've a problem when I'm in the checkout process as guest user or registering on the onepage checkout register

Once that the user complete the billing information and does click on next (siguiente) the checkout enables the next step (shipping information) but doesn't makes it visible so the user has to do click on the shipping information title to see that page.

How can I make it automatically visible

My development environment is  http://www.voisense.com